# Opencv, finding pixel value

Tags: c++, opencv

update - in the process of troubleshooting, trial and error I got my mats mixed up.  Its working now

I was wondering if anyone can help troubleshoot my program.  Here's some background.  I'm in the early stages of writing a program that will detect parts along a conveyor belt for an automated pick and place robot.  Right now I'm trying differentiate an upside down part to a right side up part.  I figured I can do this by querying pixels at a certain radius and angle from the part center point.  (ie, if pixels 1,2, and 3 are black, part must be upside down)

Here is a screenshot of what I have so far:
[image]

Here is a screenshot of it sometimes working:
[image]

The goal here is if the pixel is black, draw a black circle, if white, draw a green circle.  As you can see, all the circles are black.  I can occasionally get a green circle when the pixel im querying lays on the part edge, but not in the middle. To the right, you can see the b/w image that I am reading, named "filter".

Here is the code for one of the circles.  Radian is the orientation of the part, and radius is the distance away from the part centerpoint for my pixel query.

```
// check1 is the coordinate for 1st pixel query
Point check1 = Point(pos.x + radius * cos(radian), pos.y + radius* sin    (radian));       Scalar intensity1 = filter.at<uchar>(Point(check1));  //  pixel should be 0-255
if (intensity1.val[0]>50)
    {
    circle(screenshot, check1, 8, CV_RGB(0, 255, 0), 2);  //green circle
    }
else
    {
    circle(screenshot, check1, 8, CV_RGB(0, 0, 0), 2);  //black circle
    }
```

Here are the steps of how I created filter mat

Webcam stream - 
cvtcolor (bgr2hsv) - 
GaussianBlur   -->
inRange (becomes 8u I think)  -
erode -
dilate = 
Filter mat (this is the mat that I use findContours on and also the pixel querying.)

I've also tried making a copy of filter, and using findContours and pixel querying on separate mats with no luck.  I'm not sure what is wrong.  Any suggestions is appreciated.  I have a feeling that I might be using the incorrect mat format.

Comment: Use a debugger to check the value of filter.at<uchar> and make sure it is a reasonable value. If not, your filter is probably not an 8u.

Comment: ok a couple weeks ago, I realized that when you try to "findcontour", the original mat for a split second, turns dark with a faint outline of the part.  Since i wanted to see a clear b/w image, I created another mat.  Long story short, I got my mats mixed up.  Its working now.